# Is there any way to recreate this using CSS3 & HTML5

Tags: html, flash, css

I've been asked to create a system. The system involves making a UI to showcase a database of data.

A perfect example of what I want to replicate is shown in this [website demonstration](http://weavethepeople.com/w/demo/)

Can I achieve this in CSS3, jQuery, javascript & HTML5, PHP & MYSQL as I don't it having anything to do with flash.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Reasons for closing please? I think this is a perfect question, in regards to discussion of the best practises to tackle a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of database, and how do you want to connect to the database? There is no way that you will achieve this with CSS3/HTML5. In principal the visible part of the example you showed is doable with merely CSS3 and HTML5, however it is far from a best practice and you might want to check out some jQuery to get this working. There are a lot of examples available where you can figure out the inner working of this idea. For example, [this](http://codepen.io/xeroz/pen/pbFIJ) is a start.

Comment: Sorry I meant to recreate that within a browser, using whatever apart from flash. So it could be possible using CSS3 HTML5 & Jquery?

Comment: For the visual aspect, yes. For the connection with the database, no.

Comment: That link is great, similar to what I am looking for, but what about the movement of the icons? Say if I click a link, to then group the data in a different way. What would i need to do to apply the transition?

Comment: Ofcourse I could, using php & mysql too

Comment: With PHP and MySQL you'll be fine. For your question, I'm not sure about understanding it right. But I think your question aims on a specific way of implementation. jQuery will let you (visually) do anything and makes it able to show or hide elements onChange of other elements.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention PHP & Mysql, thanks for that, I was just trying to think strictly about how to get these divs floating about, changing their appearance, obviously the answer is jquery